# C# multiple instances of same application reading/update same oracle table, each row process once

Tags: c#, multithreading, oracle

I am writing windows application in c# in. Net 4.5 to forfill following functionality:

As set of time application will connect to oracle server and read data from table. It fetch  document number, download that document from storage and upload it to other storage after this application will update new ID in table.

This is very straightforward scenario for single instance. We are having huge amounts of data in our database(more than 30 millions) so planning to run multiple instances of applications on different servers.

I need help to use correct approach while reading/updating unique record as well as in multiple threads with multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement something like this:

1. Add three columns: datetime `Started`, datetime `Finished` and string `Token`. `Started` and `Token` columns should be set when record has been selected for processing. `Finished` column should be set when record has been processed.
2. Each application instance makes these steps:

   - `var token = $"{ServerName}_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";` //iteration id, you should do it for each select
   - mark records: `update records set Token = @token, Started = @now where id in (select top 10 id from records where Started is null)`
   - then select records: `select * from records where Token = @token`
   - process records
   - mark records as completed: `update records set Finished = @now where Token = @token`

In background you should handle the case when application instance selects record and fails before processing is finished:
`update records set Started = null where Finished is null and Started > Started + @some_timeout`